# Hold the Keys to move instead of spamming them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 3d game in Unity. I have made basic movements for my character.

But, when I press my movement keys in game, the character only moves once. I wanna make it so that if I hold a movement key down, the character will move forever until I release the key or the character is blocked from moving.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.W)) {
       rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: try [GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html). Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name instead of during the frame the user starts pressing down the key

Comment: Doesn't your code already do that? When the key goes down, you add a force. Unless you remove the force, it will be there forever (at least in Physics), wouldn't it?

Comment: And if I read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html), it should be the same: "Force is applied continuously along the direction of the force vector." - so to me, the problem seems to be that you remove the force somewhere. You should only remove it in [GetKeyUp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html)

Comment: @ThomasWeller ever heard about friction? ;)

Comment: Please be careful with the tags you use and read their description. Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! And the description of [`script`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/script/info) should be self-explanatory enough ;)

Comment: Yeah i heard about that , but i don't know what it is , I used GetKey instead of GetKeyDown and it worked! I am a newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetKeyDown()` will return true only on the frame you press the key. For it to return true while the key is being held down, use `GetKey()` like this:
`Input.GetKey(Keycode.W)`